# How to convert milliseconds to minutes using luxon library

Tags: luxon

I want to perform a transformation using luxon from milliseconds to minutes. 
For eg. if i enter 1000 , te output should be 1m 0s.
I am trying `Duration.fromMillis(1000).as('minutes')` but in return i am getting 0 output. Is there any other way i can achieve the same thing

Comment: `as` is giving you zero because 1000 milliseconds is a second, not a minute. Using `toFormat` is a great answer, but you might find it helpful to play with `Duration.fromMillis(...).shiftTo("minutes", "seconds").toObject()`

Answer (score 8):

```js
Duration.fromMillis(150000).toFormat("mm'm' ss's'")
```

Answer (score 2):

@snickersnack comment should be accepted as answer, as it states a very useful way to play with luxon:

`Duration.fromMillis(4515000).shiftTo("hours","minutes","seconds").toObject()`

Will create an object:

`{ hours: 1, minutes: 15, seconds: 15 }`

Than you can do what you need